# Code sometimes returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.Cannot figure out why

Tags: java, dynamic, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am trying to write code to return the lowest number of coins needed to make up a given number. The inputs to my method are an array of valid coins, and the number I try to make.

```
    public static int change(int[] d, int p) {
        int[] tempArray = new int[p + 1]; // tempArray to store set
                                            // of coins forming
                                            // answer
        for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) { // cycling up to the wanted value
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // assigning current minimum number of
                                            // coins
            for (int value : d) {// cycling through possible values
                if (value <= i) {
                    if (1 + tempArray[i - value] < min) { // if current value is
                                                            // less than min
                        min = 1 + tempArray[i - value];// assign it
                    }
                }
            }
            tempArray[i] = min; // assign min value to array of coins
        }
        return tempArray[p];
    }
```

This works for most cases, however, when I fill in the following :

```
int[] test = {2,3,4};
System.out.println("answer = " + change(test, 6));
```

The answer should be 2, right? But it prints out :

> -2147483647

What have I missed?

Comment: Add lots of debug output to the code and the answer will be obvious. For example, after the outer `for`, output 'top of for, i=` and then `i`. Before the `if`, output value, i, tempArray[i-value], and min. and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have fixed my code now, if I put a 1 + tempArray[i - value] > 0 into my if statement, the output is correct :). Is this right? Is there anything I can improve?

Answer (score 2):

Because, during the first iteration `tempArray[i] = min;` tempArray[i] is assigned to MAX, and during subsequent iteration[s], `min = 1 + tempArray[i - value];` would try to increment MAX by one, which basically shifts the bits and forms a negative counterpart.

Comment: I see, I can't really see any easy way to fix this though. I could assign min a value of Integer.MAX_VALUE - 10? Is there any better way?

Comment: Wait I think I got it, in 1 + tempArray[i - value] > 0...I just put this into my if statement?! :)